# Is this conditional sentence wrong?

Tags: grammar

"If I would have worked harder, I would have had a better job."

I know the more accepted way to put it is, "If I had worked harder, I would have had a better job."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more accepted way seems more acceptable: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if%20I%20had%20worked%2Cif%20I%20would%20have%20worked&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20had%20worked%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20would%20have%20worked%3B%2Cc0)